# "Adjust to fit" causes memory leak for UITextField category (or subclass)

Tags: memory-leaks, uitextfield, subclass, categories

When using a category on UITextField, the "Adjust to fit" and minimum font size options may cause a memory leak, when text inside such a field exceeds its visible boundaries. I tried subclassing instead, but it did not solve the problem.

Here is how my category implementation looks like:

```
    @implementation UITextField (custom)

    static NSString *fontName = @"My-Awsome-Font";
    static UIColor *color;
    static UIFont *smallFont;
    static UIFont *largeFont;
    static NSDictionary *smallAttributes;
    static NSDictionary *largeAttributes;
    static NSString *placeholder;
    static bool shouldModifyPlaceholder;

    - (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
    {
        if(largeFont == nil)
            largeFont = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:20.0];
        if(smallFont == nil)
            smallFont = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:16.0];
        if(smallAttributes == nil)
            smallAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: smallFont};
        if(largeAttributes == nil)
            largeAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: largeFont};

        // general elements
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [self.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];

        self.font = largeFont;
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
        self.clipsToBounds = YES;
        //


        shouldModifyPlaceholder = [self respondsToSelector:@selector(setAttributedPlaceholder:)] && ![placeholder isEqualToString:self.placeholder];
        // custom elements for each size category
        if (self.frame.size.width <= 90) {
            if (shouldModifyPlaceholder) {
                if ([self.placeholder length] > 3) {
                    self.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.placeholder attributes:smallAttributes];
                }
                else {
                    self.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.placeholder attributes:largeAttributes];
                }
                placeholder = self.placeholder;
            }

            return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + 18, bounds.origin.y + 9,
                      bounds.size.width - 36, bounds.size.height - 16);
        }
        else {
            if (shouldModifyPlaceholder) {
                self.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.placeholder attributes:largeAttributes];
                placeholder = self.placeholder;
            }
            return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + 20, bounds.origin.y + 9,
                      bounds.size.width - 40, bounds.size.height - 16);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I discovered that typing "too much" text into a UITextField caused my app to use up all the phone's memory and crash. I found out that it was due to the fact that my customisation did not work well with the "Adjust to fit" option. Removing "Adjust to fit" fixed the issue. I also set minimum font size property to the original font size to be sure. And since I used well over a day trying to find a solution, I thought I'd share this in case someone else runs into this problem.

[image: change these properties]